# Components which are not defined in SFC are not shown using Vue3 Router?

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vue-router, vuejs3, vue-router4

Now I am trying to create a front-end of a website using Vue3. But now I am having an issue using the Router.
Here's my code.

Main.js

```
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import router from './router'

createApp(App).use(router).mount('#app')
```

router/index.js

```
import {createRouter, createWebHistory} from 'vue-router'

const Home = { template: '<div>Home</div>' }
const About = { template: '<div>About</div>' }

const routes = [
    { path: '/', component: Home },
    { path: '/about', component: About },
  ]

const router = createRouter({
    history: createWebHistory(),
    routes
});

export default router;
```

App.vue

```
<template>
  <img alt="Vue logo" src="./assets/logo.png">
  <h1>Hello App!</h1>
  <p>
    <!-- use the router-link component for navigation. -->
    <!-- specify the link by passing the `to` prop. -->
    <!-- `<router-link>` will render an `<a>` tag with the correct `href` attribute -->
    <router-link to="/">Go to Home</router-link>
    <router-link to="/about">Go to About</router-link>
  </p>
  <!-- route outlet -->
  <!-- component matched by the route will render here -->
  <router-view></router-view>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'App',
}
</script>

<style>
#app {
  font-family: Avenir, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  text-align: center;
  color: #2c3e50;
  margin-top: 60px;
}
</style>
```

There's no content in router-view after rendering. How can I fix it?

Comment: in your `App.vue` wrap everything with a `div` and add `id: 'app'` i mean `<div id="app">everything here</div>`

Comment: Try import Home & About views from file by ```import Home from '../views/Home.vue'```

Comment: Unfortunately, It doesn't work too.

Comment: make sure your About.vue file is like this:

```<template>
  <h1>About</h1>
</template>```

Comment: Same as before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried out your example [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/affectionate-cookies-levt7) and i got the same behavior as you have but after defining components inside single files they work fine:

```
import Contact from "./Contact.vue";
import About from "./About.vue";

const Home = { name: "Home", template: "<div>Home</div>" };// this will not be displayed

const routes = [
  { path: "/", name: "Home", component: Home },
  { path: "/contact", name: "Contact", component: Contact },
  { path: "/about", component: About }
];
```